# What is the difference? "Adding more LSTM layers" or "Increasing epochs"?

Tags: lstm, deep-learning, epochs

To get more accurate results which one is better? Adding more layers or increasing number of epochs? I like to know the difference between effects of these two approaches?

Answer (score 2):

**Increasing the number of epochs** :

This is the best when you have a large and diverse dataset. A large dataset refers to a number of diverse samples in equal amounts ( no bias ). Also, you make your model generalise better, you might **increase the dropout rates** and **decrease the learning rate**. At such a time **increasing the number of epochs would help the model generalise better**. Also, since it has generalised on a diversed dataset means it can perform **well in the real world**. For LSTMs, they can make correct predictions based on the sequences.

**Increasing the number of layers of LSTM** :

If we treat each LSTM as a memory unit then we are **increasing the number of memory units** and thus the overall memory. The first sequences would be feed to the next layer hence a model could **create a hierarchical representation of the data**. This is better if you have sequences which have such a context like an image.

> On considering both the scenarios, if you have **abundant data** then the **first option is optimum**. If you have **complex data which has less diversity** then the **second and the first points** need to be considered.

Comment: How can I play with learning rate in Keras.LSTM?

Comment: I referred the learning rate which is initialized with the optimizer in the `fit()` method of your model. If you are using an RMSprop optimizer for your model then `model.fit( optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop( lr=0.0001 ) , loss='categorical_crossentropy' )` where `lr=` is the learning rate.